# Sequelize.js - Delete array of instances after 'findAll'

Tags: sql, node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

In Sequelize.js I have query to find all items under some condition. After I got array of model instances I want to delete those instances:

```
let toBeDeleted = await Request.findAll({
  where: {
    // Some where statements...
  }
});

const deleted = await toBeDeleted.destroyAll(); // <= Need something like this

// Some actions with array `toBeDeleted` (For example, Delete file associated with each row)
for (let i in toBeDeleted)
            await fs.removeSync(path.join(global.config.paths.screenshots, toBeDeleted[i].image));
```

I need to delete what I found first and then delete associated files with row.

Answer (score 2):

```
const { Op } = require("sequelize");

let toBeDeleted = await Request.findAll({
  where: {
    // Some where statements...
  }
});

// get ids of scoped instances that you want to delete
const toBeDeletedIds = toBeDeleted.map(el => el.id);

await Request.destroy({
    where: {
      [Op.and]: {
        id: toBeDeletedIds, // this will make your destroy scoped to this ids
        // Some where statements...
      }
    } 
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

use where once and then destroy using findAll data. replace below code with delete part of the original answer.

```
await Request.transaction(async function (t) {
      for ( var i = 0; i < toBeDeleted.length; i++){
          await toBeDeleted[i].destroy({ transaction: t });
      }
});
```

---

like this ?

```
let toBeDeleted = await Request.findAll({
  where: {
    // Some where statements...
  }
});

const deleted = await Request.destroy({
   where: {
    // the same statements you used to find toBeDeleted
  }
});
```

keep in mind if you have **paranoid: true** , then records will not be deleted and only **deletedAt** column will have a time string, if you want to force delete the record you need to use **force:true**

Comment: Sure this is one way, but I wanted something where I can use where statement only once and then use already fetched data.

Comment: @DavidBubeník i believe you can only do so with for loop inside a transaction.